# Abaqus and Tkinter windows freeze with start of mainloop

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, freeze, abaqus

I'm working on numercial simulations in Abaqus 2020 and coded a GUI with Tkinter.
My problem is, that while running the Tkinter code everything works well unitl the start of the mainloop. Then both windows of Tkinter and Abaqus freeze. When I first close the Abaqus window, the Tkinter Window works correctly. I tried sth with threads but wihtout success..

Setup: Windows 10, Abaqus 2020, Python 2.7

here you find a minimal example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *


# Creating master Tkinter window
window = tk.Tk()

window.title('TKINTER-mini')
# window.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
width=1200
window.geometry("1800x1000")
# Frames
frame0 = Frame(window, width=width)


label_Titel = tk.Label(master=frame0, text ='Test', font=('Aerial 15 bold'))

label_Titel.grid(row=0, column = 0)
frame0.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20, pady=20, ipadx = 20, ipady=20)


window.mainloop()
# window.update()
```

I'm looking forward to get some help. Thank you in advance!

Greets JBKingPile

I tried

```
#1
def __init__(self):
    import threading
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

def shutdown_ttk_repeat(self):
    self.mainroot.eval('::ttk::CancelRepeat')
    self.mainroot.destroy()


def __init__(self, parent):
    self.mainroot = parent
    # self.mainroot.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.shutdown_ttk_repeat)
    # self.tabpage()
    self.root.after(1000, self.refresh())
    self.root.mainloop()

#2
try:
    # Tk will crash if pythonw.exe has an XP .manifest
    # file and the root has is not destroyed explicitly.
    # If the problem is ever fixed in Tk, the explicit
    # destroy can go.
    try:
        gui = gui(window)
        window.mainloop()
    finally:
        window.destroy()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

#3
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `self.root.after(1000, self.refresh())` will immediately call `self.refresh()` and then pass the result (probably `None’`) to `after`

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley, thank you for your comment. This was just a test but didn’t work. Do you have any idea how I can get the code run without freezing windows?